# How can I check the max_concurrency_level of a warehouse in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to check the max_concurrency_level of my warehouses after it was changed by an admin to see if it went through but can't find a way to do that.

I tried querying SHOW WAREHOUSES and using the UI Admin>Warehouses>Details

Answer (score 4):

SHOW PARAMETERS IN WAREHOUSE <>;